# How do you store dynamic site settings in the database?

Tags: c#, database-design, asp.net-core-mvc

How do you store dynamic site settings/design in the database?

Previously, I have stored it in a table looking something like this:

```
public class SiteSettings
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FooterText { get; set; }
    public string CopyrightInformation { get; set; }
    public string TextColor { get; set; }
}
```

When writing data I checked if a record exists. If not, create one. If it exists, update it. In other words, never have more than one record in that table.

When reading the data, I did this:

```
SiteSettings settings = await db.SiteSettings.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Is there another, better way of doing it?

Comment: This question can really only be answered with an opinion in its current form, and we don't know anything about you context to be able to judge what is "better" or "worse". What is your complaint with the way you do it currently?

Comment: As for the DB: as from your example you would like to use an ORM, EF Core is very populair: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: @stefan I don't necessarily think it's an anti pattern; styling data has to be stored somewhere, be that in a db or in a css file on a disk (which is like a db) referenced by a db. We know very little of why this way was chosen so we can't automatically jump to presuming its "wrong" until we are told why it no longer meets the requirements? It might be that one day the site is styled per customer in which case it makes sense to have some sort of configuration of branding in a db.. inflexible as this is it might not be wrong for the requirements (whatever they are)

Comment: note also that SO is not for software recommendations, but there is a dedicated SE site for it - softwarerecs.se

Comment: @CaiusJard: since `TextColor` is in there, I think it's worth to mention. Obviously it depends on the use case - but this seems to have a high level of customization and I would like to give OP a heads up that he might want to reconsider the setup. Just trying to give alternatives. I know OP didn't ask for it - I just want to provide the alternative perspective. For example OP could also just store HTML. Let's see - I'll remove my comment after OP read it.

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't necessarily have any complaints, but I was wondering if it was a conventional way of doing it. I have taught myself C# and Asp.Net Core mostly using SO and youtube, so I'm always assuming I'm not doing things the optimal way.

Comment: @Stefan How do you let the site admin change the footer text if it's not in the database? Reading and writing text files?

Comment: @Stian: You could let the admin alter the HTML files. Or; as compromise: store the HTML in the database. The drawback is that the site admin must be more technical. The reason why I mentioned is that, walking this path, you might end up building a complete new HTML translator - or a CMS if you like - , since you might want to include: backcolor, text style, font, positioning. That's why I pointed out an alternative choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can always store it in JSON format in one table, one row, one column. But it will be close to field name changes a little bit, so new settings you will add later, they will have to be nullable types in your class definition. And if you wanna play around with names and class structure later, you might have to manually fix the changes on DB too.. The advantage of this would be, you could design your settings class in nested objects and wouldn't have to deal with making different tables for each nested objects:

```
{
  SiteTitle : "My Web Site",  
  Theme: "Dark",
  DbSettings : {
     ConnectionString : "",
     ConnnTimeout : 30
  },
  HomePage : {
     WelcomeMessage : "Hello!"
     MainMenu : {
       Position : "left",
       ShowIcons : true
     }
  }
}
```

If this doesn't fit you and you still want to store fields separately on your DB table, then I would suggest storing your settings in Key, Value structure in multiple rows and find the setting you want with its key from the list. Otherwise you will have to deal with adding new properties to your class every time you need one, add the column to database, re-build, re-deploy, etc.. Besides, if this is a long-term project, your table column number will increase in time with new requirements and it will be pretty ugly after a time. But if you store Key/Value it's a bit more work at the start, but less work in the future..